# Contour lines by joining a set of 2D ordered points without line intersection

Tags: data-visualization, splines

I was recommended on StackOverflow to ask this question here: for me it's dataviz question, but perhaps it's more algorithmic in nature.

I have an ordered set of points in 2D, and would like to join them using some sort of spline to form a closed loop that does not intersect itself. This is, in fact, a single contour line, and I have additional sets of points marking out further contour lines that should be sequentially nested inside each other. Do any dataviz procedures exist to do this without intersection? For instance, take the 23 black points in this picture as the outer contour and the 12 blue points as an inner contour. [image: Points to join]

I would want to join them vaguely like this:[image: Lines through points]

If it helps, I'll probably be trying to visualise this in R.

Comment: It would be far better to begin with the data from which the contour line was generated. Do you have those data?

Comment: @whuber: thanks, but unfortunately for your suggestion, these *are* the data. They are points positioned along branches on a fractal tree (actually one of [these](http://www.onezoom.org)). The "contour line" is purely to visualising how far along each branch you have travelled (in this case, a geological date).

Comment: Why are there two of each point number (except the highest)? How exactly are these numbers related to the tree?  If you do have a tree, *that is extremely useful information* so it would be good to know exactly what your original input is.

Comment: The number is simply the order I wish to join the points: there is no correspondence between the black (1) and the blue (1) in my diagram. I agree in principle about the tree, but I'm not sure how it would help in this case. For the gory details, have a look at one of the trees at http://www.onezoom.org. The nodes on the trees mark increasing geological time to the present (but time is not related to branch length). An instant of geological time corresponds to a set of points along the branches (time=0 corresponds to the leaves on the tree). I wish to draw isolines for time around the tree.

Comment: What do the black and blue colors in your diagram mean, then, and why do you draw two isolines? An alternative approach to your situation might be to draw a set of parallel linear (or perhaps concentric circular) isochrones and then arrange the nodes along each of them in breadth-first order, finally connecting those into the tree. In effect this distorts the tree in a continuous manner so that the isochrones become simple, which might be a superior way to visualize the temporal aspect of these data.

Comment: The black line is one isochron, the blue line is one further back in time. I will want to plot multiple isochrones, but for the purposes of the question, I only showed two.

Certainly I could distort the tree to make the isochrones simple shapes. But for various reasons that’s not ideal. Surely there must be algorithms to fit smooth lines through points that avoid line intersections?

Comment: Sure there are--but there are arbitrarily different ways to do it. For instance, you could seek minimum-length or minimum-curvature solutions--but they would look quite different from each other and from the ones you have drawn. To obtain a good solution, it needs to be guided by the objective of the analysis and you need to establish a quantitative way to compare different solutions to determine which is better for your purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15195/discussion-between-user2667066-and-whuber).